# Passing Pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

Apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere, I wasn't sure exactly how to word a search for this.

My question is if I pass a pointer to a function, does that function get a copy of the pointer or the actual pointer that was passed?
in other words, if I have

```
printNext(myClass* foo)
{
    foo = foo->next;
    cout << foo;
}
```

will foo be changed permanently or just temporarily in the scope of the function?

if it is changed permanently, how do I make it not do that?
should I use printNext(myClass*& foo) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a *copy* of the pointer to `printNext`.  Any changes to the parameter will change the *copy* and not the original.

If you want to change the pointer, either pass by reference or pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: perfect, thanks! do you know any good free resources that go in depth about pointers and this kind of thing?

Comment: @Jackson consider a good C++ book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list